# Does retyping and declaring variables that could otherwise be inherited degrade performance

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance, inheritance, import

I'm wondering about the performance differences between imports and inherits in a `.net` app.

I currently program by creating multiple classes that logically define my objects. e.g. a class for `customers, users` and `product`.

When i want to use these classes in a page i have to import them eg. "`Imports Custmomers`" and then later in my code i have to create a variable and datatype it before i can use the sub routines and functions from class.

I understand from a coding perspective this keeps it all neat and tidy.

So my question Would it be not better to combine all my classes into a base class, inherit that base class, rather than import it, when i want to use it and so cut down on the extra declarations and associated code that come from importing a class; and if i did this would it aid performance?

Comment: Collapsing code into one class will not improve performance at all.  It *will* make your codebase harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: sounds like you're misunderstanding some concepts here. Imports in asp.net (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx) is only a help for the compiler to tell it in which namespaces to look for your types, and has *nothing* to do with runtime performance. at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not improve performance to use a base class instead of separate classes, it will just make the application harder to maintain and extend. [Prefer composition over inheritance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steverowe/archive/2008/04/28/prefer-composition-over-inheritance.aspx).

If you're having performance problems with your application use a profiler and check where the hotspots are.

"Importing" a class is just a way to tell the compiler that you are too lazy to type the fully qualified names of the types all over your code and has no impact on the runtime performance.

Comment: In my base class i was thinking about defining variables such as "sqlstr" that i would use every time i wanted to define a custom SQL String. I have been reading about dispose and the garabge collector and about unmanaged objects and how .net decides when it it best to remove things from memory. I'm wondering if another reason not to  combine my classes into one would be because variables such as "sqlstr" would stick in memory even if they are not being used but are there simply because they would have been defined in my base class.

Comment: I'd advise you to think about object oriented design instead of trying to optimize memory usage. Fields belong on the classes that are having a behavior that involves using the data. If you don't need the data for the operations on a class, it's probably in the wrong place. The main reason that you in general want to think hard before you create a base class is not about memory usage, it's about flexibility and extensibility as stated in the article I linked. Check out Craig Larman's work on the [GRASP patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)) for OOP guidance.